# storing a string in linked list in c

Tags: linked-list

i am very new in programming and its my 2nd semester in my college an dour teacher teach us about linked list and malloc function where we can make a node dynamically and increase or decrease its size . our teacher teach us how to store a integer value in list like this

```
struct node
{ 
  int num;
  struct node *next;
}head;
```

but i want to store a string say "name" of students in linked list instead of integer .. so i want to know how to do this ..
i write this code for that

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
struct node
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    struct node *next;
};
//
void addatbegin(struct node **q,char name [20],int age)
{
    struct node *r;
    r=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    r->name=name;
    r->age=age;
    r->next=*q;
    *q=r;
}
//
void addatend(struct node **q,char name[20],int age)
{
    struct node *temp,*r;
    if(*q==NULL)
    {
        temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->name=name;
    temp->age=age;
    temp->next=NULL;
    *q=temp;
    }
else {
    temp=*q;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
r=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
r->name=name;
r->age=age;
r->next=NULL;
temp->next=r;
}}

void main()
{
    struct node *head;
    int age,ch;
    char name[20];
    head=NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("***** MENU ****** \n");
        printf("1.Add at Begining of List\n");
        printf("2.Add at End of List\n");
        printf("3.Print the list\n");
        printf("4.Exit\n \n");
        printf("Enter Your choice:- ");
        scanf(" %d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case1:printf("Enter Name:- ");
            scanf(" %s",name);
                        printf("Enter Age:- ");
                        scanf(" %d",&age);
 addatbegin(&head,name,age);
 break;
        }
getch(); }}
```

---

but its shwoing error lvalue missing

Comment: Which is the line of your error?

Comment: In the `struct node`, the variable `char name[20];` is still allocated. Replace `temp->name=name;` by `strcpy(temp->name,name);` in both `addatbegin()` and `addatend()` functions.

Comment: Bro can u explain me why we have used strcpy ?? And is there any way to store the name directly without using strcopy .. Just only by passing value of name to function and just writing temp->name=name ?? Why method is wrong ?? Can u explain